# Есть ли простой принцип общения между двумя приложениями в пределах одного компьютера?

Tags: java

*Эти 3 вопроса взаимосвязаны с вопросом о реализации одного проекта, но были распилены.  Перед вами первый.*

[Второй,](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457000/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-jvm-2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) [третий.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457001/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-javafx-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Есть GUI интерфейс который как запускается, так и выключается. И есть две операции, которые периодически выполняются. Причем одна маловесна, вторая до жути прожорлива.

**Можно ли запустить эти операции отдельным фоновым приложением и при запуске GUI просто засылать запросы ему (а не через файл общаться)?**

**UPD В частности в пределах одного компьютера без задействования пересылки каких либо файлов?**

Comment: Распаковывайте обратно, переполнение стека вопросов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5) очень давняя и большая тема. Способ этого взаимодействия так же много(можете по ссылке посмотреть). И этому взаимодействия совершенно не важно, на одном компьютере запущены процессы или же на разных.

Т.к. вы используете Java, то я бы вам посоветовал использовать либо [RMI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI) либо [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).
По RMI есть большой [офф. гайд](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/). С REST больше заморочек, но он более универсален, т.е. клиент может не быть написан не только на Java.
Только не очень понятно по постановке вопроса, чем вас обычные [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) не устраивают? Или же более продвинутые [Thread worker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Посмотрите в сторону протоколов RPC (remote procedure call). Например, [google protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview)

Comment: Интересная реализация, хотя у меня была схожая идея, общения через файл с помощью велосипеда, который я делаю параллельно. А просто на уровне одного пк без реализации каких либо файлов, стрингу посылать?

Comment: Если оба процесса на одном ПК проще всего использовать родной RMI.

Comment: В Java не силён, к сожалению. В своих проектах на C++ использую именно protobuf - и становится не важно запущены сервисы на одной машине или на разных.