# Можно ли реализовать в JVM 2 реальных потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность

*Эти 3 вопроса взаимосвязаны с вопросом о реализации одного проекта, но были распилены. Перед вами второй.*

[Первый,](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456999/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8) [третий.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457001/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-javafx-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Есть GUI интерфейс который как запускается, так и выключается. И есть две операции, которые периодически выполняются. Причем одна маловесна, вторая до жути прожорлива.

**Насколько я помню в JVM все потоки виртуальны, реально ли все-таки распилить эти операции на 2 реальных потока? Например если отдельными приложениями?**

Comment: Чего вы этим хотите добиться? Вы ожидаете, что "реальные" потоки будут обрабатываться более эффективно, чем "зеленые"? А на взаимодействии между ними проблемы не появятся?

Comment: Взаимодействие - не проблема, потоки имеют конечную цель о которой отчитываться надо в файл или бд. Я рассчитываю что ос справится с распределением между ядрами на порядок лучше. И не надо думать что я каждый поток хочу расщепить на отдельное приложение!

Comment: Вы знакомы с [Java EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)? Самое главное в Java GUI приложениях не запускать тяжеловесные процессы в EDT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы ошибаетесь, никаких зелёных потоков уже сто лет нету, их давно выпилили. Все потоки реальные, нативные. Вот, например, [почитайте в википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads#Green_threads_in_the_Java_virtual_machine):

> In Java 1.1, green threads were the only threading model used by the JVM, at least on Solaris. As green threads have some limitations compared to native threads, subsequent Java versions dropped them in favor of native threads.

Можете там по ссылкам на источники пройтись. В общем, смело создавайте потоки и ничего не бойтесь.

Comment: Спасибо, успокоили!

Comment: @Tagir: В .NET, наоборот, ввели снова green threads в форме async/await, и это типа фишка.

Comment: @VladD, ну по факту всякие `CompletableFuture` в Java-8 тоже шаг в эту сторону, просто на уровне библиотеки, а не на уровне языка. Хотя насчёт .NET не в курсе, может, у вас там умнее сделано. В нормальных зелёных тредах возможен context-switch в произвольном (ну не совсем, но всё же) месте. Async/await включает такую возможность?

Comment: @TagirValeev: Там немного не так. Допустим, у меня есть код `Button.Active = false; int result = await Calculation1(); int result2 = await Calculation2(result1); Button.Active = true;`. Тогда я хочу, чтобы `Button.Active = true;` выполнялось в том же контексте, что и `Button.Active = false;`. Поэтому метод _во время_ `await Calculation1()` может менять контекст, как ему заблагорассудится, но по окончанию возвращается в исходный контекст.

Comment: @TagirValeev: С другой стороны, если у меня чисто модельный метод, я не хочу тратить время на возвращение в исходный контекст. Тогда я могу написать так: `async Task<int> Do() { int result = await Calculation1().ConfigureAwait(false); return await Calculation2(result1).ConfigureAwait(false); }`, и внутри метода `Do` контекст «уплывёт». Если вызывать так: `Button.Active = false; int result = await Do; Button.Active = true;`, то этот код возвращается назад в исходный контекст.

Comment: @TagirValeev: Кроме того, Task/green thread может временно выполняться **вообще нигде**. Например, если он дожидается чтения байта из интернета или таймера, он не занимает никакого физического потока.