# Обработчик нажатия клавиш из трея

Tags: java, javafx, клавиатура, fxml

Есть прорамма, которая при запуске сворачивается в трей. Нужен хук клавиатуры, чтобы при нажатии например Ctrl+Shift+I выполнялась определенная функция.  Смотреть в сторону JNI, или есть способы попроще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал библиотек [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook):

Пример для вашего случая.

1. За основу приложения, сворачивающегося в трэй, возьмем [пример из
   поста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457001/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-javafx-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9)
2. Добавляем [зависимость](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.1stleg/jnativehook/2.0.2) в pom.xml
3. Добавляем немного своего:

   ```
   public class Main extends Application implements NativeKeyListener

   ...
   @Override public void start(final Stage stage) {

       ...

       stage.setScene(scene);

       stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
           GlobalScreen.removeNativeKeyListener(this);
           try {
               GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
           } catch ( NativeHookException ex ) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
       try {
           GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
       } catch ( NativeHookException ex ) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {
       if ( nativeKeyEvent.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_I
               && "Shift+Ctrl".equals(NativeKeyEvent.getModifiersText(nativeKeyEvent.getModifiers()))) {
           Platform.runLater(this::showStage);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {}

   @Override
   public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {}
   ```

Ctrl+Shift+I приведет к появлению окна приложения.

Comment: спасибо! именно то, что я искал.